# Repeatable way to remove a row from a data frame that ends in a certain character

Tags: r, string, for-loop

So, I have a small data frame and like my title says, I would like to remove all rows that end in a certain letter, "n".

Here is the code that will give you the data I am working with:

```
url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1980.html"

library(XML)
x1 = readHTMLTable(url)

east.1980 = x1[["E_standings"]]
west.1980 = x1[["W_standings"]]

east.1980 = east.1980[c(1,2)]
west.1980 = west.1980[c(1,2)]

names(east.1980) = c("Team", "W")
names(west.1980) = c("Team", "W")

wins.1980 = rbind(east.1980, west.1980)

wins.1980$Team = gsub("\\b\\d+\\b", "", wins.1980$Team)
wins.1980$Team = gsub(" +"," ",gsub("^ +","",gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]","",wins.1980$Team)))

View(wins.1980)
```

Here is an example of how the data frame will look:

```
                Team    W
1   Atlantic Division   �
2   Boston Celtics      61
3   Philadelphia 76ers  59
4   Washington Bullets  39
5   New York Knicks     39
6   New Jersey Nets     34
7   Central Division    �
8   Atlanta Hawks       50
9   Houston Rockets     41
10  San Antonio Spurs   41
11  Indiana Pacers      37
12  Cleveland Cavaliers 37
13  Detroit Pistons     16
14  Midwest Division    �
15  Milwaukee Bucks     49
16  Kansas City Kings   47
17  Denver Nuggets      30
```

So basically, I want to remove the division rows "Atlantic Division, Central Division, etc...". It just so happens that all of these strings end with "n", so I am trying to write a for loop to remove all of the rows where the `wins.1980$Team` string ends with "n".

I want to be able to repeat the process over 30+ years of the data so being repeatable is a must.

Here are the two for loops I have tried so far:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(wins.1980)) {                      
  if ((str_sub(wins.1980$Team[i], -1)) == "n") {    
    eval(parse(text=paste0("wins.","1980","[-", i, ",]")))  
  }
}




for (i in 1:nrow(wins.1980)) {
  if ((str_sub(wins.1980$Team[i], -1)) == "n") {    
   wins.1980[-i,]                      
  }
}
```

I have used a for loop with `if ((str_sub(myData$Column[i], -1)) == "letter")` to do something if the last character was equal to `"letter"` so I am pretty sure that part of the loop works.

Since there are only 6 divisions in the NBA, I would be okay with something that was repeatable and said `if (wins.1980$Team == "Atlantic Division" | "Midwest Division" | etc...)` then remove that row, however I do not feel like the problem in my loop is selecting the right rows, just removing them.

I do not get any errors when I run each of the above loops, it runs, but I think it just does not save what it does or something.

Pulling from my example data frame above, I would like to result to look like:

```
                 Team   W
2   Boston Celtics      61
3   Philadelphia 76ers  59
4   Washington Bullets  39
5   New York Knicks     39
6   New Jersey Nets     34
8   Atlanta Hawks       50
9   Houston Rockets     41
10  San Antonio Spurs   41
11  Indiana Pacers      37
12  Cleveland Cavaliers 37
13  Detroit Pistons     16
15  Milwaukee Bucks     49
16  Kansas City Kings   47
17  Denver Nuggets      30
```

And again, I would like to be able to repeat this over many more data frames. Any ideas?

I am pretty new to R so I might by oblivious to simpler solutions and simplicity would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an easier way:

```
wins.1980[grep("Division$", wins.1980$Team, invert = TRUE), ]
```

`grep("Division$"...` matches anything that ends in "Division" in the `Team` column (this is probably safer than choosing anything that ends in n, but you could do that with the same technique), and `invert = TRUE` inverts these matches so you get everything that *doesn't* end in "Division". Using this to subset gets you all the rows where `Team` doesn't end in "Division".

You could make this a function to apply to many data frames:

```
no_div <- function(x) {
  x[grep("Division$", x$Team, invert = TRUE), ]
}
```

Assuming you want to subset them all based on the `Team` column; if you're using different columns you'd have to modify the function to take an additional argument. Then call it on your data with `no_div(wins.1980)`.

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was going to suggest. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grepl` like so,

```
df <- data.frame(Team=c("Boston Celtics","Atlantic Division",
                        "Central Division","Atlanta Hawks"),
                 W=sample(10:20, 4))

df <- df[!grepl("n$", df$Team),]
```

Where "n$" is a regular expression meaning 'string ends with n'

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use substr and subset to do this.

First find the rows which end in Division

```
matches <- substr(wins.1980$team,nchar(wins.1980$team)-8,nchar(wins.1980$team)) %in% c("Division")
```

Then subset the dataframe based on this

```
wins.1980 <- subset(wins.1980, !matches)
```

Edit: better example here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13012423/1502898

Answer (score 1):

If you like the syntax of the `dplyr` and `magrittr` packages:

```
library(dplyr) ; library(magrittr)
wins.1980 %<>% filter(!grepl("Division", Team))
```