# How to apply function startsWith to several patterns?

Tags: r, dataframe, stringr

I have a dataframe. I want to write condition for creating a column which depends on other column. Here it is:

```
tab <- tibble::tribble(
  ~dataset_id,  ~type,
     "Site4H",      268,
     "Site4D",      479,
     "SIte8H",      345,
     "Site8D",      567,
     "Site8K",      507
  )
library(dplyr)
tab %>%
  mutate(state = case_when(
    endsWith(dataset_id, "H") ~ "healthy",
    endsWith(dataset_id, "D") ~ "disease",
    TRUE                      ~ NA_character_
  ))
```

Comment: Use `stringr::str_ends` and `stringr::str_starts` instead. Then you can do something like `stringr::str_ends(dataset_id, "H|K")`

Comment: See this also [Select rows from data.frame ending with a specific character string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012275/select-rows-from-data-frame-ending-with-a-specific-character-string-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions with the rebus package for your task

```
library(dplyr)
library(rebus)
library(stringi)

# look for a string ending with H or K
pattern <- or("H", "K") %R% END

# gives you true if pattern is found else false (you can negate that with ! in fron of stringi
tab %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(state = stringi::stri_detect_regex(dataset_id, pattern))

  dataset_id bacteria state
  <chr>         <int> <lgl>
1 Site4H          268 TRUE 
2 Site4D          479 FALSE
3 SIte8H          345 TRUE 
4 Site8D          567 FALSE
5 Site8K          567 TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grepl`/`str_detect` to match with the pattern.

To match with either "H" or "K" you can write this as :

```
library(dplyr)

tab %>%
  mutate(state = case_when(
    grepl('H|K', dataset_id) ~ "healthy",
    endsWith(dataset_id, "D") ~ "disease",
    TRUE                      ~ NA_character_
  ))

#   dataset_id bacteria state  
#  <chr>         <int> <chr>  
#1 Site4H          268 healthy
#2 Site4D          479 disease
#3 SIte8H          345 healthy
#4 Site8D          567 disease
#5 Site8K          567 healthy
```